# how to create new project after update on android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

After creating new project on android studio updates i am getting following error.

> AAPT err(1031123794):
>   D:\Sushma\Work\android_studioWork\main_projects\Fragment_Anifarm\fragment_daily_‌​anifarm_vikas\Frag_Marathi_EAnifarm\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.andr‌​oid.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0-beta1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_t‌​op_mtrl_alpha.9.png
>   ERROR: Unable to open PNG file Error:(27, 34) No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value
>   '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha')
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\sushma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: clean project and try again or try to restart studio.

Comment: Build -> Clean Project 
and then go to

Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: it is giving me like

Comment: AAPT err(1031123794): D:\Sushma\Work\android_studioWork\main_projects\Fragment_Anifarm\fragment_daily_anifarm_vikas\Frag_Marathi_EAnifarm\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0-beta1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
Error:(27, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').

Comment: check this `abc_cab_background_t‌​op_mtrl_alpha.9.png `  image in drawable folder or not ?

Comment: i cleaned,rebuild,and restarted android studio,still its giving error

Comment: no this image not there

Comment: but \app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.0.0-beta1\res\drawable\abc_edit_text_material.xml

Comment: this xml is present

Comment: yes yes that image is also present

Comment: that image must be in `drawable` folder.

Comment: yes it is in drawable folder